# How can I get all Products fromcategory and subcategories

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

Getting all children from specified category then pulling products from all the childrens

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
$lids = $_category->getAllChildren();
$ids = explode(',',$lids);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
echo '</pre>';
if ($ids)
{
    foreach ($ids as $id)
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        if($cat->getIsActive()==1)
        {
        $category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('megamenu_category_product')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category1);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                if ($product->getData('megamenu_category_product') == true){
                    echo "<div>" . $product->getData('name') . " - ". $product->getSku() . "</div>";
                    break;
                }else{
                    //echo 'FOO<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

because I used '->addAttributeToSelect("megamenu_category_product")'
it won't display product->getName()
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/11/06/magento-get-all-category-and-subcategory-products/ .. doing a google search is more faster than adding a question here.

Comment: I managed to do it but still  ... would you look at the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();

$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();

if ($ids)
{
     foreach ($ids as $id)
  {
     $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
     $cat->load($id);
     if($cat->getLevel()==3 && $cat->getIsActive()==1)
     {
        $category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                             ->addCategoryFilter($category1);
        echo "<b>".$cat->getName()."</b><br>";
        foreach ($products as $product) { //print_r($product->getData());exit;
                echo " &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; " . $product->getName() . " - ". $product->getSku() . "<br/>";
        }
     }
  }
}
```